# How to get all the changed files in between two revisions in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Suppose, I have 2 revisions in SVN: Revision 140 and Revision 185. I had modified/checked-in around 100 files. Now I want to get the list of all the files which have been changed from revision 140 to 185.

If I compare revisions 140 and 185, I will get only the list of files which are changed/modified in these 2 revisions only not in all revision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is

```
svn diff -r 140:185 --summarize
```

This works in a shell, but I don't know about [tortoisesvn](/questions/tagged/tortoisesvn).

Comment: It only gives difference between two version not all the files which have changed in between.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to achieve. Can you update your question and outline what's not working when using my code snippet?

Comment: I have to run this command for each and every version. First for 140:141, then 141:142....184:185 to get the list of all the changed files and then get their unique by going to the notepad++. Isn't there any command which does it in one go?

Comment: I just tried, it works for me exactly the way you want to have it.

Comment: No, its not same. I have tried it. I had checked in more than hundred files since revision 140. When I tried your command svn diff -r 140:185 --summarize >> abc.txt and when I tried your command for each and every revision for a number of times as I have mentioned like svn diff -r 140:141 --summarize >> xyz.txt, then svn diff -r 141:142 --summarize >> xyz.txt .........upto.......svn diff -r 184:185 --summarize >> xyz.txt.................number of lines were more in xyz.txt file as compared to abc.txt file

Comment: You're double counting files that you changed more than once between the two revisions in question.

Comment: Works like a charm. Does anyone know how to get version diffs sorted by author?

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by @pfnuesel is correct--one cannot get more concise than that! I am only offering this in the event you might want to mine the data further. Since you flagged the question TortoiseSVN you are presumably on Windows and thus have access to PowerShell. I wrote a small suite of tools to analyze Subversion meta-data, notably my `Get-SvnLog` cmdlet.

The (approximate) equivalent to @pfnuesel's answer is this:

```
Get-SvnLog -ByFile -RevisionRange 140:185 | % { $_.path } | Sort-Object -Unique
```

But the power of `Get-SvnLog` comes in when you understand that it converts SVN meta-data to objects. This command, for example, will list all the properties of each file:

```
 Get-SvnLog -ByFile -RevisionRange 140:185 | Format-Table -auto
```

Getting more discriminating, this will report for each file the last time it was touched and how many times it was touched within the range of revisions specified:

```
Get-SvnLog -ByFile -RevisionRange 140:185 |
group Path | 
select `
    @{ n='Last Touched'; e={@($_.group | sort date -Descending)[0].date} }, `
    @{ n='NumberOfTimesTouched'; e={$_.count} }, `
    name |
sort name |
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

You can see the API for Get-SvnLog in my [open source bookshelf](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/APIbookshelf.html), which includes 20 other examples. Open the PowerShell "book" and go to SvnTools. Download the code [here](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/download.html).